# Illegal circular reference among navigation files with deeplinks Navigation Components

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-manifest, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to generate deeplinks for different navigation graphs, when I include the graphs which have deeplinks I got this error

> Manifest merger failed : Illegal circular reference among navigation
> files when traversing navigation file references starting with
> navigationXmlId: main_graph
>
> Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent {
> act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE]
> dat=myapp://test flg=0x10000000 }

What I'm doing is getting the graphs inside my activity that has the deeplinks to navigate

```
<activity
            android:name=".framework.activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/main_graph" />
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/second_graph" />
        </activity>
```

what could be the problem ?

Comment: Encountered same problem. Did you find any resolution?